# Cocoa error 3840 using JSON non latin characters being parsed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I already checked and my JSon is valid.

I try to pass it off to my app with this code

```
NSURL *actualURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[serverURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSError *errorJson;
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:actualURL options:kNilOptions error:nil]; 


        jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
```

I am getting the 3840 error code in the NSJSONSerialization

jsondata is (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray btw.

I tried many solutions I found online but it isn't working.

Does anyone have any ideas? I think the problem might be that some of the data being parsed are Greek characters (UTF8_unicode_cl collation on the server).

Here's my JSon example data btw

[{"diseaseID":"18","diseaseName":"test disease 1","diseaseDescription":"test disease 1 description","diseaseDoctor":"\u03ba\u03b1\u03c1\u03b4\u03b9\u03bf\u03bb\u03cc\u03b3\u03bf\u03c2","diseaseImagePath":"test disease 1"}]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you may be looking in the wrong place.  I suspect your NSData is garbled somehow -- some extraneous values have crept in.  NSLog `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and make sure all the characters outside of quoted strings are valid.

Comment: (I note you're not checking `error` on the data transfer.)